# Workspace is closed for code trying to access JavaModel

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code (non-plugin project):

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;

public class JavaModelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    }
}
```

I have included all the required libraries (jar). I am getting this following error while running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:412)
    at cucumbertest.JavaModelTest.main(JavaModelTest.java:9)
```

Note similar error occurs for a plugin-project as well.

Please help.

Comment: No idea what I am talking about, but the javadocs say *Returns the workspace. The workspace is not accessible after the resources plug-in has shutdown.*  Do you have to call start first?

Comment: You need to execute this as a JUnit Plug-in Test so that the runtime can start and stop your plug-in dependencies accordingly. This is like trying to invoke a Servlet class directly instead of inside a Servlet container.

Comment: You can't access the workspace from a plain Java program - it will only work in plugins or a headless RCP.

Comment: Yeah i also read that somewhere but could not verify that as it doesnt make sense. If i include all the plugin dependencies why should a non-plugin project be able to say IProject?

Comment: Most of the plugins that your plugin references require a lot of initialization - this is only done when you run the plugins as a proper Eclipse application. It absolutely will not work run as a plain Java app.